# different ways to execute javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I see

First

```
$(function() {

  ...

});
```

Second

```
(function() {
})();
```

Third

```
function() {
}

$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

Maybe there are more, what are the differences?

Comment: why the love of negative vote? at least give me some 'hint' on how I could have googled it or stackoverflowed it before asking the question?

Comment: I didn't vote it down but just a preliminary internet search of those terms yields the answers.

Comment: ok.. I didn't know the search terms, what could it be?

Comment: For example: https://www.google.com/#q=javascript+what+is+(function()+%7B+%7D)()%3B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your notation is mainly jQuery (atleast the ones with `$`)

1. This is shorthand for a DOM ready function, equivalent to the bottom one
2. This is a self executing function with the parameter specified in the trailing `()`
3. This is a DOM ready function `$(document).ready(function() {});` atleast, the function above it is simply a function.

Comment: so 1 and 3 executes the code when document is loaded, 2 executes the code when the javascript is loaded?

Comment: Pretty much, if you want more info, 1 and 3 would be searched as DOM ready functions, the second would be a self executing function.

Answer (score 1):

so these indeed are a few different ways to execute javascript code, some of them are library dependent (using jQuery) others are done specifically because of differences in scope.

the first block:

```
$(function() {
  ...
});
```

is utilizing the js library jQuery that uses the namespace '$'  what you are doing here is calling the jQuery '$' function passing in the first parameter of another anonymous function... this is a shorthand way to call `$(document).ready(function(){});`... both of those statements wait for the DOM to complete loading (via the onload event) before interpreting the javascript inside

the second block:

```
(function() {
})();
```

is a procedure called an (IIFE) Immediately-Invoked Function Expression... which in essense is defining an anonymous function and calling it immediately.

the third block:

```
function() {
}

$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

represents two things... the first function declared actually should have been named something like `function myFunction(){...}` and thus could be called later `myFunction(parameters);`

and finally `$(document).ready(function(){});`  is the javascript library jQuery's way of saying grab the 'document' element of the dom, and attach an event listen to it looking for the onload event, when that event is triggered execution the function passed as a parameter...